# Laptop: Logging out increases power consumption

Tags: laptop, power-consumption

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon with Windows 10.
When I'm logged in it uses 9W, but when I log out, is uses 15W - consistent for more than 10 min.
Battery is fully charged and everything is up to date.

What could case this increase in power consumption and how can I lower it?

Comment: When you say log out, do you mean log in as a different user, or return to the lock screen/login prompt screen?

Comment: return to the lock screen